# Android SurfaceView Canvas Layers

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview, layer

I am trying to make an application in which you can take an image and apply 'stickers' (multiple bitmap images) to the image. Then allow the user to transform (translate, scale and rotate) each individual 'sticker'. I am currently using a `SurfaceView` and `Canvas` to draw each bitmap to that `Canvas`. It allows the user to directly transform the bitmap, and that bitmap is drawn to the `Canvas` on in the `onDraw()` function. Though currently, I can only effectively manipulate the last 'sticker' that was drawn.

I would like to make it so the user can directly manipulate each individual 'sticker'. So my current thought is that I would have to create multiple layers (i.e. Photoshop Layers) of stickers, and determine during `onTouchEvent()` which sticker is being touched, bring that layer to the front of the stack and manipulate that layer. To do this I think I would have to create multiple `Canvas` objects to use as layers, then draw each 'sticker' to a single `Canvas`. Then `onTouchEvent` would call `getDrawingCache()` on each `Canvas` to detect which sticker is being touched by calling `getPixel()` on that drawing cache, and determining if the pixel is transparent or not.

My question is essentially how would I go about drawing all of these `Canvas` objects to the `SurfaceView`? And is this the best way of getting my desired effect?

I know that `SurfaceView` takes only one `Canvas`, therefore I would have to draw each `Canvas` to a single `Canvas` beforehand? And if that is the case, would each of these `Canvas` objects keep their transformations in tact when I merge them? Or would I have to manipulate the bitmap within each `Canvas` object instead of the `Canvas` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurfaceView doesn't *take* a Canvas, it *provides* a Canvas -- note the Canvas is a return value from `lockCanvas()`, not an argument.  (It's an argument to `unlockCanvasAndPost()`, which is somewhat unfortunate.)

I think the best way to do what you want is to use off-screen Bitmaps, for which you [create your own Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)).  Do all of your rendering off screen, then blit the composed Bitmap onto the SurfaceView with a single bitmap draw call.

I should also point out that, if you're using `onDraw()`, you're at risk of rendering onto the View part rather than the Surface part.  I recommend against sub-classing SurfaceView unless you intend to draw on both.  If you think that `onDraw()` is what you actually want, then you should consider using a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and avoid the unnecessary Surface overhead.